# Is there a way to get PDFBox / Tika to ignore font information and only extract text?

Tags: memory, fonts, pdfbox, apache-tika

I'm pulling text out of PDFs to index them, using Tika 1.28.1

I'm running into some PDFs that (If I'm reading Yourkit correctly) have gigabytes of font information in memory, and they cause my app to OOM and die. Now, I don't care at all about the fonts, I just want text. I'd prefer to just ignore all font info, and not load it into memory.

Is there an config option for this? I didn't see anything obvious on PDFParserConfig, except maybe setExtractFontNames(), and that just sounds like in only controls name output.

Any other suggestions to minimize memory usage?

Comment: Does the problem happen with the current tika version? The one you mention is old.

Comment: Upgrading shortly, and will test. Are there fixes to this in newer versions? And I note from the FAQ "Sometimes the PDFont contains vital information needed for text extraction.". So, ignoring all font info is not an option?  Thanks!

Comment: PDFBox once had a bug that it was using too much memory. It could be that this is the cause. And yes the fonts are needed for text extraction because one needs to know how PDF code <=> Unicode.

Comment: @curiousity did upgrading help resolve OOMs. I am running into similar issue now and would like to know if you managed to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

the workaround is to use pdfbox manually before sending document to tika

1. split the pdf document per page
2. convert every page to an image (as I remember there is a 2-step)

- page to bufferedImage
- bufferedImage -> png: ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bufferedImage, "png", out, dpi);

then send the n images to tika for ocr the text